# Filter words in a sentence that begin with a certain range of letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

My task is to print all words in a sentence whose first letter is within a range of letters, for example: h-z.

This is my code so far, however it still prints words which begin with "g" and does not print the last word.

```
famous_quote = input("Enter a one sentence quote: ").lower()
word = ""

for ltr in famous_quote:
    if ltr.isalpha() == True:
        word = word + ltr         
    else:
        if word > "g":
            print(word)
            word = ""
        else:
            word = ""
```

I'm only allowed to use ASCII comparisons, I've tried to compare the ASCII values but I don't know how to go about it in this context.

Sample input:

```
Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart
```

Sample output:

```
WHERESOEVER
YOU
WITH
YOUR
HEART
```

Algorithm I've come up with:

```
 - split the words by building a placeholder variable: word
 - Loop each character in the input string
 - check if character is a letter
 - add a letter to word each loop until a non-alpha char is encountered
 - if character is alpha  
 - add character to word    
 - non-alpha detected (space, punctuation, digit,...) defines the end of a     word and goes to else
 - else
 - check if word is greater than "g" alphabetically
 - print word
 - set word = empty string
 - or else
 - set word = empty string and build the next word
 - Hint: use .lower()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a neat little generator to split your sentence into words and compare the first letter of each.

```
def filter_words(sentence, lo, hi):
    lo, hi = map(str.upper, (lo, hi))
    words = sentence.upper().split()

    for word in words:
        if lo <= word[0] <= hi:
            yield word
```

```
sentence = 'Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart'
print(*filter_words(sentence, 'h', 'z'), sep='\n')

WHERESOEVER
YOU
WITH
YOUR
HEART
```

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me...
The task is: Create a program inputs a phrase (like a famous quotation) and prints all of the words that start with h-z

I was making the mistake of using word > "g" before, which needs to be replaced by word > "h".
Also, you need to add the last print command in order to print the last word in case the phrase does not end with a punctuation (as in the given example)

```
phrase = input ("Please enter a phrase: ").lower()
word = ""
for letter in phrase:
    if letter.isalpha():
        word += letter
    else:
        if(word > "h" ):
            print(word)
            word = ""
        else:
            word = ""
if word.lower() > 'h':    
    print(word)
```

Comment: Could you explain some of the code to make the answer useful to future readers? [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18353980)

Comment: Hi, I have added some explanation to be clearer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I approached this problem. It gave me a hard time since I am a beginer. But it seems to work fine.

```
 quote = "quote goes here"

   word = ""

for letter in quote:
        if letter.isalpha():
            word += letter

        else:
            if word > "":
                print(word.upper())
                word = ""
            else:
                word = ""

    print(word.upper())
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the space to the user_input and also used the word > 'h'. Below is how it looks:

```
user_input = input('Enter a phrase: ').lower()
user_input += ' '
word = ''
for char in user_input:
    if char.isalpha():
        word += char
    else:
        if word > 'h':
            print(word.upper())
            word = ''
        else:
            word = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the famous quote contains only spaces as word separator, this should do the job:

```
words = input("Enter a one sentence quote: ").lower().split()
for word in words:
 if word[0] > 'g':
  print("{w} ".format(w = word))
```

*split()* transforms a string into a list (array). It takes, by default, the space character as parameter (hence I did not give the argument) and returns the list of words.

*print()* can be used in a lot of ways, due to python's history with this function.

You can .join() the list (getting a string as result) and print it:

```
print(" ".join(words))
```

you can also print with concatenations (considered ugly):

```
print(word+" ")
```

or you can use formatted printing, which I do use a lot for readibility:

```
print("{w} ".format(w = word))
```

interprets "{w}" and replaces it with *word* wherever "{w}" appears.

Print formatting is rather CPU consuming (but it is still really fast). Usually any print operation slows your application, you want to minimize making outputs if you are making CPU intensive apps in your future (here I don't do that because CPU is not the main concern).

Comment: And how is this different from my answer?

Comment: @Coldspeed: man diff :-D *joking*
 we just posted at the same time. Your solution is more performant on the CPU that's why I upvoted it. However I like my format :-) a total CPU killer haha

Comment: There's a 6 minute difference. ;/

Comment: A lot of things can happen within 6 minutes of a man's life :-)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I'm new to programming and I have no idea what you did on your last line of code. Could you please explain ? I'd very much like to know. Also, are you able to tell me what the split() function does in simple language ?

Comment: I edited my post, I hopes this enlightens you a bit.

Comment: It has, I'll try to keep the info in mind for the future. The Edx course has not covered arrays and the use of {} braces yet. I need to learn python for my systems biology course and for research and so far the struggle is real.

Comment: Don't worry for the braces: they are not python's braces but markers for print() to work. As for your struggle, we all went there. Everything will be more easier after your first 3 months of practice. Good luck!

Comment: @fortiswdg It is good to know why your current approach does not work. Please look at my answer for that. Also, if this or any other answer helped you, consider marking that answer as accepted so as to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Just one comment on the exercise, as a programming exercise this approach is fine but you would never do it this way in practice.

The two issues you've highlighted is that you are comparing the whole word instead of just the first character.
Simply change:

```
if word > "g":
```

To:

```
if word and word[0] > "g":
```

And if the quote doesn't finish with a punctuation you will miss the last word off, just add after the loop:

```
if word:
     print(word)
```

You may note the output is all uppercase, so  `.lower()` the whole quotation may be an issue, alternatively you can just `.lower()` the comparison, e.g.:

```
famous_quote = input("Enter a one sentence quote: ")
...
    if word and word[0].lower() > "g":
```

Note: You can simplify your `else:` condition:

```
else:
    if word and word[0] > "g":
        print(word)
    word = ""
```

Comment: If I use 

    if word[0] > "g"

I get 

    IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: You may need to check there is a `word` first, for the cases where you have 2 punctuation in a row e.g. `'. '`. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that you are not allowed to use the `split()` method.  I am not sure what you can use, so here's a solution (not the optimal one).

```
famous_quote = input("Enter a one sentence quote:") + ' '
current_word = None
for c in famous_quote:
  if ('a' <= c <= 'z') or ('A' <= c <= 'Z'):
    if current_word is None:
      current_word = c        # start a new word
    else:
      current_word += c       # append a new letter to current word
  else:
    if current_word is not None:
      f = current_word[0]     # first letter
      if ('h' <= f <= 'z') or ('H' <= f <= 'Z'):
        print(current_word)
    current_word = None
```

Here is a sample run of the program. It preserves lowercase and uppercase.  It also splits words on any non-ASCII character.

```
Enter a one sentence quote: Whereever you go, there you are!!!
Whereever
you
there
you
```

Note: Since printing is done when a non-ASCII character is encountered, a non-ASCII character is appended at the end of `famous_quote`.

Answer (score 0):

> #### 1. Split the words by building a placeholder variable: word
>
> Loop each character in the input string
>    and check if character is a letter. Then add letter to the variable "word". Loop until a non-alpha char is encountered.
>
> #### 2. If character is alpha or (alphabet)
>
> Add character to word.
>   Non-alpha detected (space, punctuation, digit,...) defines the end of a word and goes to the "else" part.

```
input_quote = input("Enter a 1 sentence quote, non - alpha seperate words: ")
word = ""

for character in input_quote:
    if character.isalpha():
        word += character
```

> #### 3. Else
>
> Check if word is greater than "g" alphabetically. Print word and set "word = empty" string.

```
    else:
        if word and word[0].lower() >= "h":
            print("\n", word.upper())
            word = ""
```

> #### 4. Or else
>
> Set word = empty string and build the next word.

```
        else:
            word = ""

if word.lower() >= "h":
    print("\n", word.upper())
```

> The last "if" is explicitly coded to print the last word if it doesn't end with a non-alpha character like a space or punctuation.

Comment: Some comments about this piece of code and what it does would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I did this exact same problem. The issue most people are having (and no one seemed to point out) is when you encounter double punctuations or a punctuation followed by a space.

This is the code I used.

```
phrase = input("Please enter a famous quote: ")
word = ""

for letter in phrase:
    if letter.isalpha() is True:
        word += letter

    elif len(word) < 1: <--- [This is what accounts for double punctuations]
    word = ""

    elif word[0].lower() >= "g":
            print(word)
            word = ""

    else:
        word = ""
print(word) <--- [accounts for last word if not punctuated]
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable "word" already contains your last word of the phrase but since it does not fulfil the condition to enter the loop it does not gets printed. So you can check the below solution.

```
phrase = input("Enter a phrase after this: ")
word = ""
for char in phrase:
      if char.isalpha():
            word += char
      else:
            if word != "":
                  if word[0].lower() >= "h":
                        print(word.upper())
                        word = ""
                  else:
                        word = ""
if word[0].lower() >= "h":
      print(word.upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
phrase=input("Enter a one sentence quote,non-alpha separate words: ")
word=""

for character in phrase:
    if character.isalpha():
       word+=character
   else:
       if word.lower()>="h".lower():
            print(word.upper())
            word=""                  -----this code defines the end of a word 

       else:
            word=""


print(word.upper())              ------this will print the last word
```

Comment: According to the other answers, yours seems not to address the scope of the question. However, to make your answer easier readable and for quicker reference it is recommended to post your code sample as text with code formatting instead of a screenshot stored on an external site.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the advice but my answer is not a screenshot. I wrote it in code format and this code addressed the question. I'm taking the same online class and I got the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `regular expressions` and `list compreshension` as shown in the function below.

```
def words_fromH2Z():
    text = input('Enter a quote you love : ')
    return [word for word in re.findall('\w+', text) if not word[0] in list('aAbBcCdDeEfFgG')]
```

When I test the function by putting in the input "I always Visit stack Overflow for Help", I get:

```
words_fromH2Z()

Enter a quote you love : I always Visit stack Overflow for Help 

['I', 'Visit', 'stack', 'Overflow', 'Help']
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me. I had to add the last two lines of code because without them, it wasn't printing the last word, even if it began with a letter between h and z.

```
word = ""
quote = input("Enter your quote")
for char in quote:
    if char.isalpha():
        word += char
    elif word[0:1].lower() > "g":
            print(word.upper())
            word = ""
    else:
        word = ""
if word[0:1].lower() > "g":
            print(word.upper())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
famous_quote = input("Enter a one sentence quote:")
current_word = None

for c in famous_quote:
    if c.isalpha():
        if (c >= 'a') or (c >= 'A'):
            if current_word is None:
                current_word = c
            else:
                current_word += c
    else:
        if current_word is not None:
            f = current_word[0]
            if ('h' <= f <= 'z') or ('H' <= f <= 'Z'):
                print (current_word.upper())  
        current_word = None
if famous_quote[-1].isalpha():
    print (current_word.upper())
```

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). More specifically, try to explain how your answer works and format the code.